# zonedDataTime not workable

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

In build i have this error
Type mismatch: inferred type is java.time.ZonedDateTime but org.threeten.bp.ZonedDateTime was expected

```
private suspend fun initWeatherData() {
        val lastWeatherLocation = weatherLocationDao.getLocation().value

        if(lastWeatherLocation == null
            || locationProvider.hasLocationChanged(lastWeatherLocation)) {
            fetchedCurrentWeather()
            return
        }

        if (isFetchCurrentNeeded(lastWeatherLocation.zonedDateTime))
            fetchedCurrentWeather()
    }

    private suspend fun fetchedCurrentWeather() {
        weatherNetworkDataSource.fetchCurrentWeather(
            locationProvider.getPreferredLocationString(),
            Locale.getDefault().language
        )
    }

    private fun isFetchCurrentNeeded(lastFetchTime: ZonedDateTime): Boolean {
        val thirtyMinutesAgo = ZonedDateTime.now().minusMinutes(30)
        return lastFetchTime.isBefore(thirtyMinutesAgo)
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEoGJ.png)

Comment: Check your imports, you may have mixed up two libraries (`java.time` and a backport library of it for use in Java 6 and 7: `org.threeten`). Both provide a `ZonedDateTime`, but of course in different packages. Obviously, the `fun isFetchCurrentNeeded` expects a `ZonedDateTime` from one of the libraries, while you pass the other one.

Answer (score 0):

The java.util Date-Time API and their formatting API, SimpleDateFormat are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the modern [Date-Time API](http://3eb46242aad791aefa762d89a01f631aa5c09f1c73c3bae55df33bcaaa769c33caeea5adbc48).

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

Try Like This

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // The given ZonedDateTime
        ZonedDateTime zdtAbidjan = ZonedDateTime.of(
                                        LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2021, 9, 16),
                                        LocalTime.of(12, 0)),
                                        ZoneId.of("Africa/Abidjan")
                                    );
        System.out.println(zdtAbidjan);

        ZonedDateTime zdtLondon = zdtAbidjan.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
        System.out.println(zdtLondon);
    }
}
```

Output

```
2021-09-16T12:00Z[Africa/Abidjan]
2021-09-16T13:00+01:00[Europe/London]
```

<kbd>**Online Demo**</kbd>